# mongodb 4 Data directory C:\data\db\ not found

Tags: database, mongodb

I download and install the last vesrion of MongoDb which is 4.0.2 and i set the correct path variable.
When i want to start the mondoDb service using `mongod` command i got the following error:

> exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory C:\data\db\ not found., terminating

i know that i should create the directory missing, but that directory is automatically created in the following path:  **C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0**
I checked the mongod.cfg file and the correct path is already set : `dbPath: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data`

Now how to tell the mongo to look for the folder he thinks is missing in the correct path ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I had the same issue but after I create the directory `C:\data\db\` it just worked.

Comment: I know it's gonna work that way, but I wonder if there any way to use the Data folder that already exist inside C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0

Comment: have you tried runing mongod with option --dbpath?
mongod --dbpath "C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data"

Comment: gives me the following error `IllegalOperation: Attempted to create a lock file on a read-only directory: C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data`

Comment: Sorry same message :(

Comment: Weird, because it worked for me when I run as admin. Check the permission on that directory, right click -> properties -> security

Comment: This solution would work only till the command prompt is in C drive, try to change the drive and then run _mongod_, the same error would be thrown again.

Comment: Same errors - finally had to create a C:\data\db\ directory and it worked.

Comment: So, strange. I have the same error on my PC, but for some reason I do not have it on my laptop. I do not remember how I configured it there, because it was some time ago, but I do not have folder `C:\data\db\` and my node.js app is connecting to the database without problems.

Answer (score 8):

I too had the same issue after an Windows update, Mongodb did not start automatically. Creating a new directory C:data/db  will not be the right way as Mongodb has already configured the directory C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data as datapath.

Run the following command in cmd as Administrator.

```
cd C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin
mongod --dbpath="C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\data".
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

i tried to open CMD in admin mode and the error was gone. Hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

got to C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\4.0\bin\mongod.cfg file

update below fields with these values
dbPath: ....\data\db (directory path)

and restart server once

Comment: You should probably expand on your answer to provide sufficient detail for someone to be able to resolve their issue. You mention fields but do not clearly indicate what fields you are referencing and why those fields are relevant.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create the directory/folder like below -

   C:\data\db
2. open cmd at C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin and run 'mongod' command like below -

   C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\6.0\bin>mongod

problem solved!

Answer (score 0):

Quoting from the [Data directory C:\data\db\ not found](https://www.mongodb.com/community/forums/t/data-directory-c-data-db-not-found/7278) thread of the Mongo Developer Community:

> you need to point to the config file by using something like the
> following:
>
> ```
> mongod -f c:\path\to\mongod.conf
> ```
>
> or
>
> ```
> mongod --config c:\path\to\mongod.conf
> ```
>
> running just mongod, the process will use the **default** data values"

Answer (score -2):

This solution may solve your problem problem

1. Make a directory as

   sudo mkdir -p /data/db
2. That will make a directory named as db and than try to start with commands

   sudo mongod

If you get another error or problem with starting mongod, You may find problem as

> Failed to set up listener: SocketException: Address already in use
>   If you find that another error than you have to kill the running process of mongod by typing to terminal as

```
ps ax | grep mongod
```

Find the mongod running port and kill the process.
    sudo kill ps_number

Another way is to make a specefic port when starting mongod as

```
sudo mongod --port 27018
```

Comment: OP is using a Windows machine, but you give instructions for Linux.